# Average operation using numbers with decimals

Tags: bash, decimal, average

I want to get average of numbers with decimals. I wrote this but it's getting me the following error message when i write decimals numbers:

`./average.sh: line 10: 1.2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2")`

my average operation is:

```
i=1;
sum=0;

while [[ i -lt 4 ]]
    do
            read nr
            echo "scale=2; $nr" | bc -l
            sum=$((sum+nr))
            i=$((i+1))
    done
echo "scale=2; $sum / 4" | bc -l
```

How can i modify it in order to accept input with decimals? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bc` as you do below:

```
sum=$( echo $sum + $nr | bc -l )
```

Comment: i=1;
sum=0;

while [[ i -lt 4 ]]
        do
                read nr
                sum=$( echo $sum + $nr | bc -l )
                i=$((i+1))
        done
echo "scale=2; $sum / 4" | bc -l


the results are wrong: input:1.1,2.2,3,3; output:1.65

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine on my system (bash 4.4.20), but you should modify line 1 of your script to `i=0` if you want to read 4 numbers. It would help if you also provide your input along with your script.

However, a more easier way would be using `datamash` by:

```
datamash mean 1 # Calculate the mean of the first field
```

**Edit**

If you can't use `datamash`, `awk` would be good for you:

```
awk '{sum += $0} END {print sum / NR}'
```

Comment: for normal number (1,2,3,4,5,...) it works right, but for numbers with decimals (1.2, 2.3, ....) it doesn't work.
i can't use datamash on my server, i need to find an other way.
thanks

Comment: It seems like that bash doesn't like decimals since `$((11/3))` returns `3`.

Comment: @DragosDragomir I added solution using `awk`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

As `dibery` says, you need to modify to `i=0` if you want to calculate average for 4 numbers.

For reading input with decimals,

```
read -p 'Enter: ' var
nr="$( printf '%.2f' "$var" )"
```

not very elegant but could work...

For summing, I think you can't sum directly like integers in bash, so maybe try this

```
sum="$( echo "$sum+$nr" | bc)"
```

For printing the output, this is the format I prefer to use

```
bc -l <<< "$sum/4"
```

Answer (score 0):

My server doesn't accept "datamash" or "bc" utilitaries and i want to sum numbers with decimals from keyboard, not from file.

I tried some examples, but its don't work:

```
i=1; sum=0; while [[ i -le 3 ]]; do read nr; awk '{sum+=$nr} END { print "media:"; sum/i}'; i=$((i+1));done
```